# In an reasonable sized chess endgame I'm getting this error in Jupyter Notebook 6.0 and Python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error, python-chess

In an reasonable sized chess endgame I'm getting this error in Jupyter Notebook 6.0 and Python 3.10
I have this setting for my chess position and I'm using backtracking:
Also, I do not know what to add to my question so that I wouldn't obtain this error:

```
    a b c d e f g h
8 .  .  * .  .  .  .  *  8
7 .  .  .  * .  .  .  *  7
6 .  .  .  .  * .  .  *  6
5 .  .  .  .  .  * .  *  5
4 .  .  .  .  .  .  * *  4
3 * * * * * * * Q  3
2 k .  .  * * * * *  2
1 .  .  .  * K * .  *  1
    a b c d e f g h
```

Half Move: 0

THE ERROR:

```
Row 77   Col 18
            b += data  # type: ignore
        BufferError: Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized
    [E 23:38:42.427 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in zmqstream callback
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 634, in _handle_events
            self._handle_recv()
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 663, in _handle_recv
            self._run_callback(callback, msg)
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 584, in _run_callback
            f = callback(*args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 308, in stream_callback
            return callback(self, msg)
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 548, in _on_zmq_reply
            super()._on_zmq_reply(stream, msg)
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\zmqhandlers.py", line 251, in _on_zmq_reply
            self.write_message(msg, binary=isinstance(msg, bytes))
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 335, in write_message
            return self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 1082, in write_message
            fut = self._write_frame(True, opcode, message, flags=flags)
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 1057, in _write_frame
            return self.stream.write(frame)
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 533, in write
            self._write_buffer.append(data)
          File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 157, in append
            b += data  # type: ignore
        BufferError: Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized
    Exception in callback BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(3024, 1)
    handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(3024, 1)>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
        self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 202, in _handle_events
        handler_func(fileobj, events)
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 634, in _handle_events
        self._handle_recv()
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 663, in _handle_recv
        self._run_callback(callback, msg)
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 584, in _run_callback
        f = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 308, in stream_callback
        return callback(self, msg)
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 548, in _on_zmq_reply
        super()._on_zmq_reply(stream, msg)
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\zmqhandlers.py", line 251, in _on_zmq_reply
        self.write_message(msg, binary=isinstance(msg, bytes))
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 335, in write_message
        return self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 1082, in write_message
        fut = self._write_frame(True, opcode, message, flags=flags)
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 1057, in _write_frame
        return self.stream.write(frame)
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 533, in write
        self._write_buffer.append(data)
      File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 157, in append
        b += data  # type: ignore
    BufferError: Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized
```